# Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager not returning bestView in Bing Maps V8?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm migrating an application from Bing Maps V7 to V8 and I'm having an issue with the AutoSuggest. What I had been doing is when a user makes a selection in the AutoSuggest then the map would center on the location using the bestView attribute returned in the suggestion result and add a pushpin. This worked in V7.

The pushpin does get added correctly in V8 but the map is not being centred. When I checked in the debugger the suggestion result was missing the bestView attribute. When I go the [documentation for the SuggestionResult Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712672.aspx) bestView is an attribute that should be returned

The link I'm using for Bing Maps is https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=loadMap

The code I'm using is

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    credentials: bingMapCredentials,
    showDashboard: false
});

Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.AutoSuggest', function () {
var options = {
    maxResults: 4,
    map: map
};
var manager = new Microsoft.Maps.AutosuggestManager(options);
manager.attachAutosuggest('#txtSearch', '#searchBoxContainer', selectedSuggestion);
});

function selectedSuggestion(suggestionResult) {
    map.setView({ bounds: suggestionResult.bestView });
    newAddPinToMap(suggestionResult.formattedSuggestion, suggestionResult.location);
}
```

Is there a way to get the bestView attribute for suggestionResult? Is this a bug that will be fixed soon or should I be looking for a different value?

Comment: What are you typing into the autosuggest box and which suggestion are you selecting?

Comment: The values I'm using most often are

* Typing in "ho ch" and selecting "Ho Chi Minh City, Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam"
* Typing in "han" and selecting "Hanoi, Thành Phố Hà Nội, Vietnam"
* Typing in "da na" and selecting "Đà Nang, Da Nang City, Vietnam"

Comment: I've tested these and all of them return a bestView and center the map over the result. Although it is zoomed out a decent amount.

Comment: I've managed to finally reproduce this after looking at a similarly reported issue. I will log this as a bug for the team to investigate.